# How to implement a NOT killable Android App that process always exists?

Tags: android

I used Android Device Monitor and tried to "STOP" the process of Facebook, (com.facebook.katana).

It was stopped but immediately showed up in the process list again.

I was wondering to know how to implement this mechanism?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Answer the question by myself:

I assume that there is a Service returns START_STICKY on onStartCommand
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY

Comment: And this is a tutorial to explain the process priorities in Android

https://medium.com/google-developers/who-lives-and-who-dies-process-priorities-on-android-cb151f39044f